# "Response_status": "Invalid data provided", "Error": null}

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql

I am in a project of migrating an old project which is in python 2.6 to the newest current version.

**python 2**

```
except Exception,e:
                    
                    return HttpResponse(status=500,content_type="application/json",content=json.dumps({'Response':'Failure','Response_status':'Invalid data provided','Error':e.message}))
```

I have changed to this

**python 3**

```
except Exception as e:
                    
                    return HttpResponse(status=500,content_type="application/json",content=json.dumps({'Response':'Failure','Response_status':'Invalid data provided','Error':print(e)}))
```

*Note: Tried 'Error':e, 'Error':str(e) and 'Error':e.**str**()

But got a 500 response error like this

*{"Response": "Failure", "Response_status": "Invalid data provided", "Error": null}*

Need help to solve this issue guys!

Update...This is my views.py

```
def registerUser(request):
    # permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            received_json_data=json.loads(request.body)
            referralid=received_json_data.get('referralid')
            received_json_data["name"]=str(received_json_data.get("firstname"))+' '+str(received_json_data.get("lastname"))
            latestid=1
            if tbl_user_profile.objects.all().count()>0:
                latestid=tbl_user_profile.objects.latest('userid').userid + 1

            serializer = tbl_user_profileSerializer(data=received_json_data)
            if serializer.is_valid(): 
                try: 
                    if str(received_json_data.get('role')) == '3':
                        yearsago = datetime.now() - relativedelta(years=25)
                        serializer.save(dob=yearsago.date(),gender=1,userid=latestid)
                        emailid = serializer.data.get('emailid')
                        username = serializer.data.get('name')
                        password = received_json_data.get('password')
                        userid=serializer.data.get('userid')

                        role=tbl_role.objects.get(roleid=received_json_data.get('role'))

                        user=tbl_user_profile.objects.get(userid=userid)
                        myuservalues=MyUsers.objects.create_user(username,emailid,password)
                        myuservalues.userid=user
                        myuservalues.roleid=role
                        myuservalues.userPassword=password
                        myuservalues.save()

                        usersettings=tbl_user_settings.objects.create(user_id_id=user.userid,isprivacy=1)
                        usersettings.save()



                        if referralid is not None and len(str(referralid))>0:
                            relation=tbl_coach_user_mapping.objects.create(coachid_id=referralid,userid_id=userid,status=2)
  

                        response=sendMail(str(emailid), str(password), '/templates/CyberHealth/registrationTemplate.html', 'CyberHealths Registration',None)
                        verifyMyEmail(userid)
                        user={'Response':'Success','Response_status':'', 'User_Profile':serializer.data}
                        if response=='Success':
                            return JsonResponse(user)
                        else:
                            #Error occured while email send
                            return HttpResponse(status=500,content_type="application/json",content=json.dumps({'Response':'Failure','Response_status':'Invalid data provided','Error':response}))
                    else:
                        return HttpResponse(status=403,content_type="application/json",content=json.dumps({'Response':'Failure','Response_status':'User not allowed'}))
                except Exception as e:
                    return HttpResponse(status=500,content_type="application/json",content=json.dumps({'Response':'Failure','Response_status':'Invalid data provided','Error':print(e)}))
            else:
                return HttpResponse(status=500,content_type="application/json",content=json.dumps({'Response':'Failure','Response_status':'Invalid data provided','Error':serializer.errors}))
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponse(status=500,content_type="application/json",content=json.dumps({'Response':'Failure','Response_status':'Invalid data provided','Error':print(e)}))
    else:
        return HttpResponse(status=405,content_type="application/json",content=json.dumps({'Response':'Failure','Response_status':'Method not allowed'}))
```

Comment: `print(e)` will give you `None`. Did you try `str(e)`?

Answer (score 0):

It returns `null` because you are trying to return an `e` variable as is and it's an Exception object, So the solution is to return it as a string for example:

```
'Error': e.__str__()
# or
'Error': str(e)
```